# How do you automatically send push notifications to an Android device based on user defined preferences and the user's system time?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I am creating an app, and I want the user to be able to specify a time of day that they receive a push notification from the app based on their defined preferences. I would want to run a little bit of code at the specified time to generate the necessary information to include in the push notification.

Example: A user states that they want to receive a push notification at 7am every morning their time. At 7am their time, a snippet of code would run to check a few pieces of information. Once the information is returned, the push notification will be sent to the user and will be tailored to the previously returned information.

I want to be able to set this up so any user of the app can set up their time preference for the notification, and will receive a notification tailored to them (not one notification that is the same for everyone). I have read into GCM and Mixpanel, and am not finding a way to do this without manually enabling push notifications for each individual user myself. All help is appreciated. I am new to Android, so any constructive feedback is appreciated.

Comment: you can send the notification at the same time for all devices, and it's up to each device (based on user settings) when to alert the user about this notification. how about that?

Comment: and another thought, in this case you don't need push notification, let your app call a web-service in the specified time in user's settings, and that's it.

Comment: The app is going to check their current temperature at that time and send them a notification based on what the temperature is. Based on that, I unfortunately can't generate a push notification like that.

Comment: As far as the web-service. Do you have any information I could use to read more into that? Is it something that would be quick to set up? What is the cost to maintain? Any information is appreciated.

Comment: web-service is not really hard, it could be even a single web-page that takes some params and response with some json formatted data, depends on which language or scripting you are working on Java, PHP , .NET ... but it is not hard, i think you already have a server right?

Comment: I do not. This is for my final project for my Android class. This was one of the features I wanted to implement if it were possible. If setting up a service wouldn't be too difficult, I would still consider it since I want to throw the app in the play store when it's done anyway.

Comment: by a server i mean any machine that have a web-server software, like apache or tomcat, and some language allows you to do the service, if you want to publish the app on the store , sure you will need a server, a public one i mean, meanwhile your server could be your personal laptop or computer.

Comment: I didn't think of that. I can look into something like that. But would the web service be able to do what I am asking? Send the notification at the specified time tailored to the user's current temperature, for example?

Comment: the idea of web-service is not using push notification, the device will have a time set by the user, at that time, the application will call the service sending temperature as parameter, the service will do it's work and response to the device with the proper data, the application once got the response from the service will alert the user about it as a notification in the bar

Comment: This alert sent to the user would be able to be customized? Example: "The temperature is: 75ºF". That's the end goal.